# Looking for a C# URL router, but not for HTTP

Tags: c#, url-routing, mqtt

I am looking for a C# URL router component. Something very classic, taking inputs string such as `/resources/:id/stuff` and calling the appropriate methods. Something similar to the default ASP.net routing or [RestfullRouting](http://restfulrouting.com/).
However, I am not using HTTP and I don't want a full HTTP stack/framework. I am looking for something light to route my MQTT messages.
Do you know if such a component exist?

Comment: For people not familiar with RestfulRouting, can you explain exactly what it does? Can you explain how you can call methods from a string? Are you simply looking to split by `/` and obtain the parts of a relative URI? Also, requests for libraries are off-topic for Stack Overflow, so better just describe how to do what you want to do exactly.

Comment: The router takes a string route as input, and a context. It will call a method accordingly to the route. A very simple router could split by `/` and use a few `switch` blocks. A more advanced router will provide a simple API and some parsing methods. It's very common in HTTP frameworks (Rails,Express,CakePHP…).

Comment: how are you doing your mqtt implementation now?

Comment: Yes, I know what routes do in web applications, it's just not clear for what functionality _exactly_ you're looking.

Comment: @montewhizdoh : I use [m2mqtt](https://github.com/ppatierno/m2mqtt).

Comment: @CodeCaster: I have a set of methods, a string similar to an URL, and an object. I want to call one method accordingly to the string and some routing rules, with the object as parameter.

Comment: Parsing and matching strings is one thing, calling methods using strings another. I have provided an answer that does the first; for the latter, reflection is your friend. As currently stated, this question is too broad (an answer doing it all for you would be too long) or off-topic (asking for a library that does this for you). Please [edit] your question to further specify for what parts of the problem **exactly** you're looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following non-optimized, not really defensively coded code parses URIs against routes:

```
public class UriRouteParser
{
    private readonly string[] _routes;

    public UriRouteParser(IEnumerable<string> routes)
    {
        _routes = routes.ToArray();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetRouteValues(string uri)
    {
        foreach (var route in _routes)
        {
            // Build RegEx from route (:foo to named group (?<foo>[a-z0-9]+)).
            var routeFormat = new Regex("(:([a-z]+))\\b").Replace(route, "(?<$2>[a-z0-9]+)");

            // Match uri parameter to that regex.
            var routeRegEx = new Regex(routeFormat);

            var match = routeRegEx.Match(uri);

            if (!match.Success)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Obtain named groups.
            var result = routeRegEx.GetGroupNames().Skip(1) // Skip the "0" group
                                   .Where(g => match.Groups[g].Success && match.Groups[g].Captures.Count > 0)
                                   .ToDictionary(groupName => groupName, groupName => match.Groups[groupName].Value);
            return result;
        }

        // No match found
        return null;
    }
}
```

It makes a few assumptions about the input (both routes and URIs), but basically it picks the `:foo` parameter names from the routes and makes named capture groups from that, which are matched against the input URI.

To be used like this:

```
var parser = new UriRouteParser(new []{ "/resources/:id/stuff" });
var routeValues = parser.GetRouteValues("/resources/42/stuff");
```

This will yield a dictionary of `{ "id" = "42" }`, which you can then use as you like.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added delegates to your solution and it's exactly what I needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I quickly changed @CodeCaster's solution to attach and invoke delegates.

```
public class UriRouter
{
    // Delegate with a context object and the route parameters as parameters
    public delegate void MethodDelegate(object context, Dictionary<string, string> parameters);

    // Internal class storage for route definitions
    protected class RouteDefinition
    {
        public MethodDelegate Method;
        public string RoutePath;
        public Regex RouteRegEx;

        public RouteDefinition(string route, MethodDelegate method)
        {
            RoutePath = route;
            Method = method;

            // Build RegEx from route (:foo to named group (?<foo>[a-z0-9]+)).
            var routeFormat = new Regex("(:([a-z]+))\\b").Replace(route, "(?<$2>[a-z0-9]+)");

            // Build the match uri parameter to that regex.
            RouteRegEx = new Regex(routeFormat);
        }
    }

    private readonly List<RouteDefinition> _routes;

    public UriRouter()
    {
        _routes = new List<RouteDefinition>();
    }

    public void DefineRoute(string route, MethodDelegate method)
    {
        _routes.Add(new RouteDefinition(route, method));
    }

    public void Route(string uri, object context)
    {
        foreach (var route in _routes)
        {
            // Execute the regex to check whether the uri correspond to the route
            var match = route.RouteRegEx.Match(uri);

            if (!match.Success)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Obtain named groups.
            var result = route.RouteRegEx.GetGroupNames().Skip(1) // Skip the "0" group
                                   .Where(g => match.Groups[g].Success && match.Groups[g].Captures.Count > 0)
                                   .ToDictionary(groupName => groupName, groupName => match.Groups[groupName].Value);

            // Invoke the method
            route.Method.Invoke(context, result);

            // Only the first match is executed
            return;
        }

        // No match found
        throw new Exception("No match found");
    }
}
```

That can be used like this:

```
var router = new UriRouter();

router.DefineRoute("/resources/:id/stuff",
    (context, parameters) => Console.WriteLine(parameters["id"] + " - " + context)); 

router.Route("/resources/42/stuff", "abcd");
```

That will print `42 - abcd` on the standard output.

Comment: The first optimization that could be applied is to pre-build the regular expressions in the constructor as opposed to each method call. You also may want to add some parameter checking, such as routes with duplicate variable names or no variables at all.

Comment: Yes, I updated my code to build the regex only once.